# How to make / generate the trailing effect?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation, freestyle

If an object is moved from Point A to Point B using the **Follow Path** constraint, I want it to leave behind a trail of color behind it.

**Note** : I have enabled **Freestyle** under which i have unchecked **Use Surfaces / Solid** in the Layers Tab -- **NO TEXTURES** are a set to the object.

This is what the render output looks like:

[image]

**UPDATE** : Since, freestyle has it's limitations, I was thinking of parenting a ribbon at the bird's tail, that would give a similar trailing effect, however, I want the ribbon's Freestyle Strokes to fade away long it's length. Also, what is the most suitable cloth modifier preset to simulate a ribbon?

Comment: Like a particle system trail?

Comment: @pycoder think, like the bird is trailing a rainbow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't fully get you reference to your freestyle setup, but a simple way could be using a mesh deformed by and also following the curve, using a blend texture influencing the mesh alpha.

This is a single color example, but it should be possible use a rainbow style texture...

[image]

you could combine such a trail with the freestyle based animation, perhaps... maybe using different render layers.

**edit**: since you asked here is a possible similar setup with cycles (renders a bit slower)

[image]

**edit:** since you asked, here is the .blend related to the last example (cycles)

[image]

Note: the animation is not done with follow path here, but animating the Y location after setting a curve deform modifier... the effect is similar, though.

Comment: Can the same be achieved in Cycles Render? I am neither comfortable nor remotely familiar with using Blender Render

Comment: Yes, I think so. It should be just needed a node based "colorband" texture, see this post: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?248307-How-to-use-blend-texture-with-Cycles-I-have-no-color-inputs&p=2207589&viewfull=1#post2207589

Comment: I added a cycle example above.

Comment: could i have your .blend file to experiment on?

Comment: sure, there you have it now :)

Answer (score 1):

How about dynamic paint to bring in a material in the trail? Not putting this forward as an answer... just wanted a way to post an image with the suggestion....
[image]

Freestyle did not recognize the trail, but I was using paint rather than a mesh deform, which it might.

Comment: Nah, i need the scene to render in Freestyle exclusively as a project requirement.