# In 2D animation, how to gradually reveal an object, while keeping the backgrount unchanged? (version 3.0.1)

Tags: animation, masking, 2d

I am working on a simple 2D animation.
I have few "images imported as planes", among which a plane I use as a background.

Now, I would like to have an effect of gradually revealing an object, while keeping the background unchanged.
In other words, at frame zero only the background is visible; then gradually more and more parts of the object (another image imported as a plane) are revealed, e.g. from left to right.

My guess is to do it with a "mask" object, with some special property: the object I want to show is always in the same place, with no change, but the special mask slides in front of it, gradually revealing it.

I have seen this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75783/growing-a-shape-with-changing-color/75891#75891) and then this other [question/answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/is-there-a-blender-alternative-to-chroma-key-rendering-in-opengl/74355#74355), but they refer to an older version of Blender, and I am too new to the software, so I wasn't able to replicate it in the version I am using.

However, I am open to other methods!

Please, give step-by-step directions, I am new to Blender. I am using version 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup, to get this kind of effect:

[image]

[image]

Note: play around by changing x/y coordinate or adding both ;)

Value has a driver init, just write "#frame" in it to get frame values.